# Does reciprocity apply in appliances power consumption?

Tags: power-electronics, energy, time

Normally, microwave ovens have a timer and a power selector. Similarly in other machines, you can control the power and the time you use that power.

Is it generally true **in real life** that the final energy expenditure will be approximately the same as far as `power x time` gives the same result?

In other words:

- should I get the same electricity bill if I microwave my food at 800 Watts for 1 minute than if I do it at 100 watts for 8 minutes?
- will I use the same gasoline if I drive at 80 mph for 10 minutes, than if I drive at 10 mph for 80 minutes?

- assume all the hypotheticals, i.e. the microwave works exactly the same, room temperature is exactly the same, amount of food is exactly the same, etc. In the second example, the road and car conditions are exactly the same, etc.

Comment: The power selector on a microwave usually turns the microwave on and off to lower power. So 50% power is 5 s on and then 5 s off.

Comment: I don't think this is what reciprocity means.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Car experiences a lot more drag from air at 80mph than 10mph. It also takes more energy to accelerate the body mass to 80mph than 10mph, so more energy is already consumed when required speed is reached. Also in addition yo the factor, there is some offset, because a car consumes fuel even if you go at 0 speed and let the engine run for 10 minutes.

Now, microwaves ovens can be assumed to be more simpler.

Also they generally not adjust the power, but how much the full power is applied during some time period. So sure they consume a surge every time the emission starts, but it might be more closer to average. So 800W at 100% time for full 800W power, and 800W at 1/8 duty cycle which might be 10 seconds on 70 seconds off for 100W average.

But bear in mind that microwave ovens have other circuitry such as the lamp, and a 800W rated oven will have rated output of 800W, but it will take around 1200W-1300W of electrical power in so there are losses that go to heat instead of microwave output.

Answer (score 0):

No, real devices have inefficiencies and a base current draw. While you're calculations are for and ideal device, if you consider that part of the device will draw same power (like the light and electronics and turntable motor) no matter what the power level is. This will contribute to making the device more inefficient at doing it's job with time. This inefficiency will be low for most devices, but still contribute to power loss over time.

Run the microwave for shorter times of you want to conserve small amounts of power.

Answer (score 0):

> should I get the same electricity bill if I microwave my food at 800 Watts for 1 minute than if I do it at 100 watts for 8 minutes?

Yes. Actually, the "power" selector on most microwaves actually just turns the power on and off every few seconds, so both of those options would be doing full power for one minute, it's just that in one case, that one minute of power on is spread out over 8 minutes! There will be a tiny difference due to running the fan and turntable for those 8 minutes, but I don't think that was what you were trying to ask.

> will I use the same gasoline if I drive at 80 mph for 10 minutes, than if I drive at 10 mph for 80 minutes?

No, because driving at 80mph doesn't use 8 times the engine power as driving at 10mph — it uses more. There are several sources of energy loss in a car cruising at a steady speed, but at speeds above 50mph, air resistance is far and away the biggest one, and air resistance increases as the *square* of speed. Within that regime, going twice as fast uses roughly *four* times the power, and even though it only takes half the time to cover the same distance, the result is still double the energy used.

Comment: "Inverter" microwaves don't just switch ON-OFF-ON-OFF to get the set power. Inverter microwaves are able to reduce the magnetron current without burning out the emitter heater.  "Inverter" microwaves are becoming common now, so you shouldn't just assume fixed-output magnetrons.

Comment: @david all I said was "most". And it's still most.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the system you are talking about. As other said, the microwave will be slightly less efficient (culinary result notwithstanding) at so called "low power" because of its specificity.

But in general, something using more energy faster will be less efficient because it will tend to generate more heat and this heat may reduce the efficiency of the system (increasing electric resistance, mechanical friction, heat loss, and so on), by modifying the properties of the material composing the parts of the system.